# How can I make a script executable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new to Linux. I'm trying to make a script that prints something and initiates a shutdown command. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash    

echo Hello WOOOOORRRRRLLLLDDDDDDD

echo sudo poweroff
```

Every time I try to run my script,using

```
chmod +x Hello World BASH
```

or
    ./Hello World BASH

however, I get this error message:

```
chmod: cannot access 'Hello': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'World': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'BASH': No such file or directory
```

In general, everytime I try to run this script, the "no such file or directory" error message popped up. How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: You are mistaken about something somewhere... the only way you could get output like that is if you either had `chmod` in the script, or if you were typing that in an attempt to run it, rather than typing the name of the script.

Comment: @psusi I acutally used chmod at first, but it gave me the same output as running it regularly

Comment: @wjandrea either with ./ or with chmod u+x, both gave me a no such file error

Comment: @dabberson567 Please post the full command that you are running. And please [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: @wjandrea sorry about that, clarified my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

Run these commands in this order:

```
chmod +x "Hello World BASH"
./"Hello World BASH"
```

#### Long answer

A filename with spaces has to be quoted (with single or double quotes) or escaped (with backslashes) so that the shell understands that it's all part of the filename. Otherwise, it will break on the spaces and interpret one filename (`Hello World BASH`) as three filenames (`Hello`, `World`, and `BASH`)

Also `chmod +x` does not run the script, it makes the script executable.

By the way, if you don't have have execute permissions for a given file, you can call the interpreter to run it:

```
bash "Hello World BASH"
```

Comment: bash: ./Hello World BASH: No such file or directory

Comment: Thats the error message that keeps on returning.

Comment: @dabberson567 The the file doesn't exist in the wd. Maybe you could run `ls` and see if the file is there.

Comment: How did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Because the file name has spaces in it, you need to use quotes or escapes so the space does not make it look like 3 different file names:

```
chmod a+x "Hello World BASH"
"./Hello World BASH"
```

Or

```
chmod a+x Hello\ World\ BASH
./Hello\ World\ BASH
```